# Hide keyboard in WebView for specific pages

Tags: java, android, html, webview

I have created a simple `WebView` app for work to let workers fill out forms.
At 2 points they have to scan barcodes (the tablet has a built in scanner).

My problem is, that the scanner requires focus on the input and so the soft keyboard will pop up, which is not needed at this point and looks quite a bit confusing.

I have tried several approaches found on stackoverflow and google to hide the keyboard without success.

The point is to hide the keyboard only on specific pages (where the scanner is uses) and is still available on other pages, where it is needed.

The page for the `WebView` is built in `HTML` and `JS`. So a JS Solution might work, but I would prefer a real `Java` solution.

Code i use currently that checks for url and tries to hide the keyboard (unsuccesful). As you can see i've tried several solutions but none of the worked.

```
@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

    Log.d("WebView", "your current url when webpage loading.." + url);

    if(url.equals("https://********/index.php?show=kontrolle&step=4")) {
        this.activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        Log.d("WebView", "should hide now!");
        //view = activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        //InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager) this.activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        //imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        //this.activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
        //this.activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In manifest.xml file write below code

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

Comment: Wont this hide the keyboard at all? I just want to hide it on specific pages.

Comment: Thanks for the update. But the problem is not to check for the URL (i do this in `onPageStarted`, see above) but to find a way to completly disable the keyboard for this specific url

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
//hide keboard:
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
//and for show keyboard
imm.showSoftInput(myEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Comment: I've tried this too, Take a look at the first 3 comment line in my code. Or do i miss something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand `WebViewClient` please visit [this url](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29)

1) First of all, you need to add WebViewClient and while change page you can get current url at `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` which check current url and compare it with your url and hide keyboard

for example :

```
WebView webview = new WebView(context);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

            Log.d("WebView", "your current url when webpage loading.." + url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.d("WebView", "your current url when webpage loading.. finish" + url);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onLoadResource(view, url);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            System.out.println("when you click on any interlink on webview that time you got url :-" + url);
//compare here your URL and hide keyboard
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    });
```

**Code for the hide soft keyboard**

> Here are **two** methods for hiding the soft keyboard which you can keep in Common-Utils class

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    if (activity != null && activity.getCurrentFocus() != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

    }

}
```

**the second method if `EditText` available**

```
public static void forceHideKeyboard(Activity activity, EditText editText) {
    try {

        if (editText == null) return;

        if (activity.getCurrentFocus() == null
                || !(activity.getCurrentFocus() instanceof EditText)) {
            editText.requestFocus();
        }

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity
                .getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
        activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I already use `WebViewClient` and get the current URL with `onPageStarted` (see, my code above) The problem is to hide the keyboard, i can't get any mehtod to work